# Do C compilers guarantee two eightbyte field structs will be passed as INTEGER on SysV x64?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, abi, sysv

Specifically in the context of [the SysV x86-64 ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf)

If I have a struct with only two fields, such as:

```c
typedef struct {
    void *foo;
    void *bar;
} foobar_t;
```

And I pass it to a function with a definition like so:

```c
foobar_t example_function(foobar_t example_param);
```

The ABI seems to say that each eightbyte field should be passed as `INTEGER` to the function, therefore `rdi == foo` and `rsi == bar`. Similarly, when returning we should be able to use `rax` and `rdx`, since we don't need a memory pointer in `rdi`. If `example_function` is trivially defined as:

```c
foobar_t example_function(foobar_t example_param) {
    return example_param;
}
```

A valid assembly implementation, ignoring prologue and epilogue, would be:

```
example_function:
   mov rax, rdi
   mov rdx, rsi
   ret
```

Conceivably, a mentally-deficient compiler could fill the struct with `NO_CLASS` padding and make that assembly invalid somehow. I'm wondering if it's written down anywhere that a struct with only two eightbyte fields *must* be handled this way.

The larger context to my question is that I'm writing a simple C11 task switcher for my own edification. I'm basing it largely on boost.context and [this is exactly how boost passes two-field structs around](https://github.com/boostorg/context/blob/develop/src/asm/jump_x86_64_sysv_elf_gas.S#L69-L74). I want to know if it's kosher under all circumstances or if boost is cheating a little.

Comment: There is no rule that a compiler conform to a targets ABI, it is the choice of the compiler author(s) what calling convention they create/adopt.

Comment: anything you see a particular compiler and version doing is specific to that compiler and version, the abi definition could change or for any other reason the compiler could change on the next release.  Probably not but there are no guarantees.

Comment: If you want to take advantage of a particular behavior then you need to test and validate supported toolchains for your product/software and limit it to those.

Comment: Ok, sure, but this is specifically asked in the context of a compiler conforming to the SysV x86-64 ABI. Perhaps I should be more clear, but I'm asking if I'm misinterpreting the ABI spec and there is a guarantee there, or if Boost is just relying on "typical" but unsafe behavior.

Comment: Inside the ABI, there is no wiggle room.  The struct padding is specified exhaustively by the ABI, so it should be as you say.

Comment: if it conforms then it conforms

Comment: The alignment requirement on page 15 of the spec is what I was missing, "Structures and unions assume the alignment of their most strictly aligned component. Each member is assigned to the lowest available offset with the appropriate alignment." So if the fields are just two eightbytes, this guarantees the layout will just use two INTEGERS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The ABI seems to say that each eightbyte field should be passed as
>   INTEGER to the function, therefore `rdi == foo` and `rsi == bar`.

Agreed, *for "global" functions accessible from multiple compilation units*, the argument structure is broken up into to eightbyte pieces, the first completely filled by `foo`, and the second completely filled by `bar`.  These are classified as INTEGER, and therefore passed in %rdi and %rsi, respectively.

> Similarly, when returning we should be able to use `rax` and `rdx`, since we don't need a memory pointer in `rdi`.

I don't follow your point about %rdi, but I agree that the members of the return value are returned in %rax and %rdx.

> A valid assembly implementation, ignoring prologue and epilogue, would be: [...]

Agreed.

> Conceivably, a mentally-deficient compiler could fill the struct with NO_CLASS padding and make that assembly invalid somehow. I'm wondering if it's written down anywhere that a struct with only two eightbyte fields *must* be handled this way.

A compiler that produces code conforming to the SysV x86-64 ABI will use the registers already discussed for passing the argument and returning the return value.  Such a compiler is of course not obligated to implement the function body exactly as you describe, but I'm not seeing your concern.  Yes, these details are written down.  Although the specific case you present is not explicitly described in the ABI specification you linked, all of the behavior discussed above follows from that specification.  That's the *point* of it.

A compiler that produces code (for a global function) that behaves differently is not mentally-deficient, it is *non-conforming*.

> The larger context to my question is that I'm writing a simple C11
>   task switcher for my own edification. I'm basing it largely on
>   boost.context and this is exactly how boost passes two-field structs
>   around. I want to know if it's kosher under all circumstances or if
>   boost is cheating a little.

It would take me more analysis than I'm prepared to expend to determine exactly what Boost is doing in the code you point to.  Note that it is *not* what you present in your `example_function`.  But it is reasonable to suppose that Boost is at least attempting to implement its function calls according to the ABI.

Comment: My point about %rdi comes from page 24 of the spec: "If the type has class MEMORY, then the caller provides space for the return value and passes the address of this storage in %rdi as if it were the first argument to the function."

My question was, now that I understand it more fully, can a compiler twist itself into classifying this struct as MEMORY by unaligning elements or padding its size to greater than two eightbytes? The answer is no, because page 15 strictly specifies how elements will be aligned and padded. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Compilers agreeing on struct layout and how they're passed by value as function args are *key* parts of an ABI.  Otherwise they couldn't call each other's functions.

Hand-written asm is not different from compiler-generated asm; it doesn't have to have to come from the same version of the same compiler to interoperate properly.  This is why stable and correct ABIs are such a big deal.

Compatibility with hand-written asm is fairly similar to compatibility with machine code that was compiled a long time ago and has been sitting in a binary shared library for years.  If it was correct then, it's correct now.  Unless the structs have changed *in the source* newly compiled code can call and be called by the existing instructions.

---

**If a compiler doesn't match the standard as-written, it's broken.**

Or maybe more accurately, if it doesn't match gcc, it's broken.  And if the standard wording doesn't describe what gcc/clang/ICC do, then the standard document is broken.

**If you had a compiler for x86-64 System V that passes a 2x `void*` struct any way other than in 2 registers, that compiler is broken, *not* your hand-written asm.**

(Assuming there aren't a lot of earlier args that use up the arg-passing registers before we get to the struct arg.)